Children's book from the late 80's early 90's with Ostrich drawn on every page
Read a children's book (3 to 6 years target audience) to my kids about a (possibly) animal protagonist that has an afternoon's adventure in  a city.  On every page of the story, there is a Ostrich in the background.  Ostrich is not the theme of the book, or important to the story line, it's just drawn there.  Actually took a couple readings to realize the Ostrich was in every scene - but not in a "Where's Waldo" kind of way.
Now I have grandkids and my grown kids can not remember this book at all.  I would like to get a copy for my granddaughter (aged 2 years), which would be about the right age group (as I recall).
Searching the Internet for any combination of "Ostrich, children, book, illustrated" does not produce correct answers.  Again, the Ostrich is not in the title of the book, or even a central character.  It's just on very page.
THX.

This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy as defined in the [FAQ]

You might be able ask questions about non-SF works on [literature.se].

For reference, our position on non SF&F anthro works.
